# Trying to call logic app URL result in authorization scheme or internal token scheme. Only one scheme should be used error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an application that is going through the results of a logic app step and needs to get to the URLs

To do this I use a httpClient and use the authorization token provided on the API page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflow-runs/get?view=rest-logic-2016-06-01&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "My Bearer token");
```

I get the error

```
The request has SAS authentication scheme, 'My Bearer token' authorization scheme or internal token scheme. Only one scheme should be used."
```

This also happens in Postman as shown below

[image]

How do I do this?  This happens in code and in Postman

Comment: How are you doing this in Postman or in code, can you please share some screenshots to know better about the issue?

Comment: I have added a Postman screenshot

Comment: I believe the URl is being used is a Http request url generated in logic app? If not where are you getting this url.

Comment: I have a repeat until loop which gets a lot of messages. The user interface is really poor for logic apps when it comes to getting the messages the box is stupidly small and would fake hours to go through messages one by 1 so I used the rest Api to get the data. It used to be possible to get the data from the links directly but I can’t now and I really need this data

Comment: which Rest API you are using? Are you trying to use `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}?api-version=2016-06-01`? If so, this doesn't look similar to your postman request URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fetch the data of a particular logic app workflow run, you can use the below URL.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}?api-version=2016-06-01
```

Initially you need a token to invoke it. To generate the token, register an application in Microsoft Entra ID as per this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application). Once registration is completed, you will get the Client Id and Tenant Id from the ***Overview*** blade as shown below.

[image]

You need to create a secret in ***Certificates and Secrets*** blade. Once you have Tenant Id, Client Id and Client Secret then you can generate the token as shown below.

***URL***-

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant_ID}/oauth2/token
```

[image]

I have used the above bearer token to fetch the output of a particular workflow run like below-

[image]

In this way, you use the REST API to get the run of a logic app workflow.